pkexec vs runuser
pkexec is not installed by default on Debian unlike runuser which is.
So far I've been using pkexec but discovered there is also runuser, and since runuser seems to be more advanced (looking at options in man entry which I don't fully understand and didn't use the command yet) so this made me think whether there is any benefit to install pkexec since runuser is already there.
What pros and cons does runuser have compared to pkexec?

The two tools are different to the point that they are not really interchangeable for most use cases, so it only barely makes sense to have a 'vs' comparison between them. (It would make more sense to compare pkexec vs sudo, or su vs runuser, or pkexec vs run0.)
Code-wise, runuser is practically a copy of util-linux's su, only slightly adapted to be more suitable for use in scripts that generally run as root but need to call some specific command as a different user. (For example, runuser uses a different set of PAM configurations than su, allowing it to be exempt from things like systemd-logind which are often desired for interactive su but would be extremely counter-productive for scripted su.)
The most visible difference between your two commands is that pkexec is usually installed "setuid root" (just like sudo or su), meaning it can function when run from a regular user account – but runuser is usually not installed that way, and in fact specifically refuses to work when run by a non-root user.
This essentially places runuser opposite pkexec, as the latter is meant almost exclusively to raise privileges to root, whereas runuser is only able to lower them from root.
In a similar way, pkexec is designed almost exclusively for interactive desktop use (with PolicyKit prompting the user for admin authentication) while runuser is designed for batch use by root (which would be exempt from such authentication) and therefore doesn't even have the ability to prompt for that.
The only overlap between them is that it is possible for root to call pkexec --user XYZ which will switch to that user without doing the PolicyKit checks (although still contacting polkitd), in which case it has almost no advantages over runuser.
